# Connecting response of spring controller with the angular js and html template

Tags: angularjs, html, spring-mvc

First of all, I'm very inexperienced with AngularJS and JavaScript.
I'm trying to link my Spring App with HTML template and Angular and I don't know how exactly to solve the problem and which functions to use.

@Controller (it returns the calculation of net salary according to chosen currency code and daily wage):

```
@RestController
public class CalculatorController {

    private final NBPClient nbpClient;

    public CalculatorController(NBPClient nbpClient) {
        this.nbpClient = nbpClient;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/calculator/{currency-code}/{daily-wage}")
    public BigDecimal calculateSalaryByCountryCode(@PathVariable("currency-code") String currencyCode,
                                                   @PathVariable("daily-wage") BigDecimal dailyWage) {
        return this.nbpClient.getCalculation(dailyWage, currencyCode);
    }
}
```

JavaScript code for Angular (experimental)

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module("githubViewer", []);

  var GitHubViewerController = function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.getRepositoryData = function() {
        var owner = $scope.owner;
        var repository = $scope.repository;
        var serviceUrl = "/repositories/"+ owner +"/" + repository

        $http.get(serviceUrl).then(onCalculationCheckComplete, onError);
    }

    var onCalculationCheckComplete = function(response) {
      $scope.repositoryData = response.data;
      $scope.showData = true;
    };

    var onError = function(reason) {
      $scope.error = "Couldn't fetch GitHub repository data";
      $scope.showError = true;
    };


  };
  app.controller("GitHubViewerController", GitHubViewerController);

}());
```

and some parts of HTML template (also with experimental Angular functions):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="calculatorViewer">
<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6"
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/main.css"/>

</head>
<body ng-controller="CalculatorViewerController">

        <form method="" action="#">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                    <input type="number" ng-model='dailyWage' name="dailyWage" min="1"
                           placeholder="Type your daily wage"/>
                </div>
                <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                    <select class="6u 12u(mobilep)" name="service">
                        <option ng-model='PLN' name='currencyCode'>Poland</option>
                        <option ng-model='GBP' name='currencyCode'>Great Britain</option>
                        <option ng-model='EUR' name='currencyCode'>Germany</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="12u">
                                <textarea ng-show="showResult" placeholder="Result" rows="6">
                                Result: {{calculationData}}
                                </textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="12u">
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li>
                            <button ng-click="calculateSalaryByCountryCode()" value="Calculate"></button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>

<div ng-show="showError">
    <h2>Something wrong happened</h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The page should load automatically and after the user chooses "country" type (input text should be different: "GDP", "PLN" or "EUR"), "daily wage" and click the button the result should be shown in the existing text area.

I'd be glad for any advice

Comment: Your question is kinda like, "figure out all the issues with all my code..." Try to get to a point where there is one specific thing that is failing and then try to cut down on your code samples for better help.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not precise with my question, but I didn't mean to figure all the code out for me. I was hoping  for advice where to look for a bug or maybe the mistake was so glaring someone could point it out.
Anyway I solved the problem.
1) The html template needed some changes. I used wrong ng-model inside the currency list
2) and the form had to be removed because it caused overloading the webpage.